# Having trouble with grouping rows - MS SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by, having-clause

I have a product table which has some duplicate records.
I need to get primarykeys **atfer grouped** them according to **names and types**

```
DECLARE @Products TABLE 
(
    pkProductId INT,
    productName NVARCHAR(500),
    productType INT
)

INSERT INTO @Products (pkProductId, productName, productType)
VALUES
(1, 'iphone', 0),
(2, 'iphone', 0),
(3, 'iphone', 1),
(4, 'iphone', 1),
(5, 'iphone', 1)
```

After I run like tsql

```
SELECT pr.pkProductId FROM @Products pr
GROUP BY pr.productName, pr.productType
HAVING COUNT(pr.productName) > 1
```

I Want To Get **These IDs**

```
pkProductId
---------------
2
4
5
```

Thank You For Your Hepls :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`row_number()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the result:

```
select pkProductId
from
(
  select pkProductId,
    productName, 
    productType,
    row_number() over(partition by productName, productType order by pkproductId) rn
  from @Products
) d
where rn >1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13114)